# Warning "Command \@makecol has changed."

Tags: fancyhdr, warnings, footmisc

When I compile my document I get the following warning `Command \@makecol has changed.`

TexStudio points to the file `footmisc.sty`. Of course I've tried to install its latest version (2011/06/06 v5.5b) but still have the problem :(

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[bottom,hang]{footmisc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
mediante DHCP\footnote{Se puede obtener más información sobre esta utilidad en el documento anexo Guía de usuario de Xen: Instalación, configuración y primeros pasos}

\end{document}
```

I've seen that by reordering the `fancyhdr` and `footmisc` sentences the warning doesn't occur, but still not sure if with that there's no error or it's just that `fancyhdr` doesn't check well.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[`footmisc`](http://ctan.org/pkg/footmisc) performs a patch on `\@makecol`. However, before doing so, it checks to make sure that its definition conforms to what it looked like at the time of writing `footmisc`. The [package implementation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/footmisc/footmisc.pdf) (section **5.1 The output routine**, p 12) mentions:

> First, we ensure that `\@makecol` is as expected from the time at which
>   these macros were written: since we're going to patch it, we had
>   better be sure that we're patching the right thing. (There was a
>   minuscule change to the definition 1999, but this doesn't as far as I
>   can tell make any difference to the semantics of the definition we base
>   our patch on.)

And indeed, [`fancyhdr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) updates the definition:

```
\let\latex@makecol\@makecol
\def\@makecol{\ifvoid\footins\footnotetrue\else\footnotefalse\fi
\let\topfloat\@toplist\let\botfloat\@botlist\latex@makecol}
```

to prepend it with some information. So, switch the load order and you'll be fine, allowing `footmisc` to perform the necessary patches before `fancyhdr` updates its definition again:

```
\usepackage[..]{footmisc}% http://ctan.org/pkg/footmisc
\usepackage{fancyhdr}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr
```

Comment: Ok, thanks :) . Maybe the developers should change the warning in footmisc like "if you want to use package fancyhdr use it after this one" It would be clearer

Comment: @Álvaro: Yes, or include it as a known issue as part of the documentation. That's typically how these things are handled. I've emailed the `footmisc` package author.

Comment: @Werner -- when you cut-and-paste something from a source prepared using computer modern, the f-ligatures are lost.  i've just restored them, but maybe you should check next time.

Comment: I also had this error occur but with the arrayparboxrestore command and the ragged2e package. Your solution of moving the package definition earlier in the document worked too.